# Testing Jetty server of Jasper Reports Integration

Tags: jasper-reports, jetty, oracle-apex

I am trying to use JasperReports integration for the first time. I am using the included Jetty server, Oracle database XE 18c and Windows 7.
I am following the quick start guide https://github.com/daust/JasperReportsIntegration/blob/main/src/doc/github/installation-quickstart.md
I downloaded the zip folder, configuired database access through adding schema credentials in application.properties file as follows...

> [datasource:default] type=jdbc
> url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XEPDB1 username=hr password=hr
>
> this parameter is limiting access to the integration for the specified
> list of ip addresses, e.g.:
> ipAddressesAllowed=127.0.0.1,10.10.10.10,192.168.178.31 if the list is
> empty, ALL addresses are allowed.

Then I deployed the jri.war file successfully. Then I started the server successfully as well. But when I tried to test it through http://localhost:8090/, I got the following page, and I do not know if that's the norm or there's something wrong...
[image]

I need to know if testing is successful, and what's meant by "context" here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You deployed the `jri.war` to the context path `/jri`, this isn't an error, and is quite normal.

Just access your webapp via `http://localhost:8080/jri/`

Comment: The jri page works well. But the Jetty page localhost:8090 shows the above error. 
Why the "404 - not found" error and the "no context on this server matched....." error?

Comment: That's not an error.  a 404 is not an error (a 5xx response status code would be an error). That's telling you that your request doesn't match any context-path, so it's listing the context-paths that are registered.

Comment: Could you elaborate further what is meant by context paths. Shouldn't it retrieve the index.html page?

Comment: And what's meant by "context"?

Comment: This is the standard servlet context path.  It's not even a Jetty thing, what you are asking about is part of the Servlet Spec.